# Edit existing DevExpress ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, devexpress

I have an existing project folder with a `.sln` file.

This project is based on DevExpress ASP.NET web forms. I have 30 day trial version of DevExpess installed.

How can I edit / modify this project as DevExpress project?

When I open this project in Visual Studio, it opens as a normal ASP.NET project.

I don't see any special menus/UI to modify this as a DevExpress project.

What is the correct way of opening/importing existing DevExpress project and then modify it?

Thanks!

Comment: I believe there is nothing special - it's just a standard ASP.NET project, and there are DevExpress web components you can use in it - but there's no special "DevExpress" project type or anything .....

Answer (score 0):

Tools purchased from say DevExpress or other vendors like Telerik etc. are just vendors of tools.

So, in place of say a gridview, or listview, they offer their own controls you can also use.

But, as such, there no such thing as vendors "x" project. You simply just open the project. As a general rule, if you installed their product, then in the tool bar, you should see a list of their tools in the toolbox + all of the asp.net built in tools.

But, the concept of a specials type of project does not exist here.

If their tools don't show up in the tool box, then you have to follow their particular instructions to ensure they do.

However, if you have their tools installed, then opening your project, ensuring a references are set to their library, then your project should build and run correctly.

I mean, just compile (build) your project. If there are missing referances, then you have to simple add a reference to their library. They should have instrucitons on how to do this. But, open the project - try building it. If it fails, due to reference errors, then add a reference to their libary, and try building again.

So, this concept of using such additonal tools with asp.net does not result in some kind of specials project, only that you have additonal tools and UI widgets to choose from during development.

You don't mention if this is a asp.net webform project, or a MVC project (they have specific packages/tools for these two choices. And now they probably started offering Blazer options, which then would be a 3rd choice.

So, you need to choose + install the correct set of tools from that vendor for say a asp.net webforms, or MVC project. (since their tools are not compatible between such different kinds of projects).

As noted, try building the project - you find out near instant if you missing the libraries and tools if the project does not build. Look for missing references in that project.